# How can I access and modify the attributes of a class stored in a vector if I delete the "original" object?

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I'm making an application that allows to quote clothes in a store.

In my `Store` class, I have defined a vector of class `Clothes`, where I must store the different types of clothing to sell (derived clothing classes such as `Shirt` and `Pants`).

My problem arises in that, it does not allow me to access the objects stored in the vector if I have deleted the "original" object. From what I understood, `std::vector` performed a copy constructor and had its own space to store data, so it is not clear to me why I am not being able to access and modify the attributes of the objects that are already inside the vector. Depending on the different solutions that I tried, the compiler showed me different read or write access errors.

PS: If I don't delete the original object (after having entered the vector), the code works fine for me, and allows me to remove it from the vector and add another object, which I CAN DELETE after entering it into the vector.

Store.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef STORE_H
#define STORE_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Clothes;
class Shirt;
class Pants;

class Store
{
private:
    std::string storeName;
    std::string address;
    std::vector<Clothes*> clothesList;

    Shirt* _shirt;
    Pants* _pants;

public:
    Store();
    ~Store();
    void setClothesPreferences(int clothesType, int alternative1, int alternative2, int quality);
    
};

#endif // !STORE_H
```

Store.cpp

```cpp
#include "Store.h"
#include "Clothes.h"
#include "Shirt.h"
#include "Pants.h"
#include <iostream>

Store::Store()
{
    std::cout << "Please, introduce your store name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, storeName);
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    std::cout << "Store address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, address);
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    _shirt = new Shirt();
    _pants = new Pants();

    clothesList.push_back(_shirt);
    clothesList.push_back(_pants);

// If I use delete _shirt here then I would get an error in setClothesPreferences()
}

Store::~Store()
{
    std::cout << "Store closed" << std::endl;
}

void Store::setClothesPreferences(int clothesType, int alternative1, int alternative2, int quality) 
{
    if (clothesType == 1)
    {
        Shirt* _shirt2 = dynamic_cast<Shirt*>(clothesList.front()); // Type-casting from Clothes (base class) to Shirt again (derived class)
        clothesList.erase(clothesList.begin());

        // SHIRT SPECIFICATIONS FOR FURTHER QUOTE
        if (alternative1 == 1)
            _shirt2->shortSleeve = true;
        else
            _shirt2->shortSleeve = false; // longSleeve

        if (alternative2 == 1)
            _shirt2->mandarinCollar = true;
        else
            _shirt2->mandarinCollar = false; // regularCollar

        if (quality == 1)
            _shirt2->quality; // Standard 
        else
            _shirt2->quality; // Premium

        clothesList.insert(clothesList.begin(), _shirt2);
    }
}
```

Clothes.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef CLOTHES_H
#define CLOTHES_H
#include <string>

class Clothes
{
public:
    std::string derivedName;
    std::string quality[2];
    double unitPrice;
    int stockAmount;

    Clothes();
    virtual ~Clothes();
};
#endif // !CLOTHES_H
```

Clothes.cpp

```cpp
#include "Clothes.h"

Clothes::Clothes()
{
    derivedName = "Base default";

    quality[0] = "Standard";
    quality[1] = "Premium";

    unitPrice = NULL;
}

Clothes::~Clothes()
{
}
```

Shirt.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef SHIRT_H
#define SHIRT_H
#include "Clothes.h"

class Shirt : public Clothes
{
public:
    bool shortSleeve;
    bool mandarinCollar;

    Shirt();
    ~Shirt() override;
};

#endif // !SHIRT_H
```

Shirt.cpp

```cpp
#include "Shirt.h"

Shirt::Shirt()
{
    derivedName = "Shirt";
    stockAmount = 2000;
}

Shirt::~Shirt()
{
}
```

My idea is actually to create a local object of class `Shirt`, insert it into the vector, and when the `Clothes` function or constructor is finished, it would be deleted, but I would still have access and modify its data from what is stored in the vector.

Comment: Putting something into a vector copies (or moves) the object. In any case, the object in the vector doesn't have any relation to the original reference.

Comment: Do you know what `std::shared_ptr` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: `Shirt* _shirt2 = dynamic_cast<Shirt*>(clothesList.front());` -- What happens if the first item is not a `Shirt`?  Your code just goes on and attempts to use a `nullptr` in this case.

Comment: Plus there are no virtual functions, other than the destructor, in `Clothes`, so why are you deriving from it?  A `Store` should know exactly where to find shirts, pants, etc.  There should be no need for dynamic casting or derivation, if you look at the design this way.  The shirts would be in a separate `std::vector<Clothes>`, the pants would be in another separate `std::vector<Clothes>`, etc.  Then maybe there is an `std::array<std::vector<Clothes>, Number_of_different_items_in_store>` that maintains the entire inventory.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I´ve been reading some things about smart pointers. However by using them I then have no way to access and modify the attributes of the derived class stored in the vector. This happens because when I store the objects of the derived classes in the vector they are transformed into objects of type Clothes (base class) and since I cannot do a Type-Casting with the smart pointers I cannot access the specific attributes of the derived class. I can only access those of the base class.

Comment: `vector` copies values inside, but the value in your case is the pointer. Try `vector<unique_ptr<Clothes>>` instead, you probably never need to "clone" a cloth anyways. If you do need, create a `virtual unique_ptr<Clothes> clone()` method in the base class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The idea is that the vector of type Clothes stores the different types of clothes available for sale (ie their derived classes). In this way, when I access to modify certain attributes or data of those derived classes through the setClothesPreferences() method, which in turn accesses the vector, I take the data depending on the type of clothing, store it in a local variable, delete its "previous version"  inside the vector and then I save the "new" one again in the same position in which it was before. In the case of the Shirt class, it is always first in the vector.

Comment: You are mistaken about "no way to access and modify the attributes of the derived class stored in the vector". `std::shared_ptr` is no different from plain pointers, in that respect; this is a completely unrelated issue, and this is exactly what virtual methods are for. In any case, Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook; you will find more information and a complete discussion of these topics in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: @PedroRob `if (clothesType == 1)` -- You know exactly this is a shirt.  So where is the need to jump through the hoops using dynamic casts, etc. if you stored the shirts in their own vector?  `if (clothesType == 1) { do something with the shirt vector } else { do something with the pants vector; }`.  When you have a design, it should mimic what you do in "real life".  Does a store stuff all of their clothes in a big pile (your universal vector implementation), or do they have their own separate spaces?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that its posible to access to methods and attributes through smart pointers. What I meant is that if I declare a `std::shared_ptr` in a local way and then I insert the pointer inside the vector,  the object turns into a Clothes object and later in the setClothesPreferences() method I cant access to an specific attributte of the derived class like Shirt. That is why I used Type-Casting in the method when I was getting the object from the vector. I´m a begginer in C++ so thats is why I´m asking for some explanation or solution here so I can understand better.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First of all thanks for your time and explanation. I understand what are you saying but the thing is that i do the dynamic cast because if I dont do it I cant acccess to some specific attributes from the derived class Shirt and I dont know another way to make it. And in respect with `clothesType` that is a reference to an input from the user when he is asked about what kind of clothes he wants to quote.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are mistaken. The object does not turn into a `Clothes` object. It is still an instance of the derived class, and virtual methods can be used to access it. See your C++ textbook for more information. Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, unfortunately, and the explanation you're looking for is in your textbook.